# Sandbox testing Receipt validation without Inapp purchase

Tags: swift, macos, app-store, receipt-validation

My product does not have any inapp purchases.All i want to check is that if the user has purchased the app from the app store as i cant implement my own licensing scheme.
I have seen many examples on receipt validation to achieve the same,All these tutorials are based on inapp purchases.
Does apple provide a receipt when the user purchases the app from the app store? If yes,how can i sandbox test it?

Answer (score 0):

Every app installed from the App Store has a receipt. You can use the same receipt validation even without In App purchase. Simply sending the receipt to the verify API will return if the receipt is valid or not.